# Make QTableWidget expand when dialog window size is changed

Tags: qt, qwidget

[image]I have a `QTableWidget`, `QTextEdit`, and cancel & okay buttons.

I want these widgets to stay in the same position relative to each other, and the `QTableWidget` to expand if the dialog window is expanded or size changed...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to look into [Qt's layout system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html) - using layouts will handle automatically resizing your objects based on the size of their parent.

A combination of using [`QWidget::setSizePolicy()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) and [`QBoxLayout::setStretch()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qboxlayout.html#setStretch) (or more likely `QBoxLayout::insertWidget(..., int stretch = 0, ...)`) will allow you to acheive the behaviour you refer to where only certain objects expand to fill available space, while others remain a constant size.

**Addressing the image you've given above as an example:**

[image: Example of solution in QtDesigner]

Aside from dragging and dropping objects into the form, to achieve this solution I have:

- Set the vertical `sizePolicy` of `textEdit` to `Fixed`.
- Set a height in `textEdit`'s `minimumSize` for the `sizePolicy` to use.
- Set `layoutStretch` in `centralWidget` to `1,0`, i.e. assign the minimum possible space for the elements contained in `horizontalLayout` and give any remaining space to `tableWidget`.

Comment: QGridLayout *layout=new QGridLayout(); ui->tableWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding); layout->addWidget(ui->tableWidget,0,0,-1,-1,Qt::AlignVCenter); layout->addWidget(ui->textEdit_2,1,0,1,2,Qt::AlignLeft); layout->addWidget(ui->cancel,1,1); layout->addWidget(ui->ok,1,2); this->setLayout(layout); but this doesnt create what i want. each of the widgets doesnt fill up the space available. only a small box is created for each widget. How do i fill the widget to each cell in the grid? and QWidget setSizePolicy() gave me error of its private and cant be used..

Comment: You've got the right idea, but if you're using Qt Designer to lay out your widgets, you can [add the layouts and specify stretch factors etc](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/designer-layouts.html), as well as setting sizePolicies (using the property editor) all without leaving Designer. The other advantage to that is that you'll be able to see the effect of all the changes you're making without having to build your application.

Comment: so i tried with layout settings in designer, and i have my widgets in a grid fashion, but the cell sizes dont change. If see my picture, i wanted my textEdit to be narrow and long and table be big... the grid is not letting me do that... idk why. how would I adjust the sizes?

Comment: based on your image above, I would not recommend using a `QGridLayout`, but instead nesting your `QTableWidget` along with a `QHBoxLayout` containing your other widgets inside a `QVBoxLayout`. See the update to my answer above.

Comment: so i tried what you've suggested, the textEdit and widgets and buttons stay in the right place and are the right sizes. However, they remain static as i enlarge the dialog window... and the tablewidget no long automatically create scroll bars when i minimize the window to a size smaller than the original tablewidget size...  (this was working when i used gridLayout)

Comment: it sounds like the problem is that your `QVBoxLayout` is not laying out the top level widget of your form, but one lower down the hierarchy - there is therefore nothing to tie the size of your window to the size of your other widgets. Does your object inspector look *exactly* as my example above, or are there some differences?

Comment: does it have to be in a mainWindow class? cuz i have mine in a dialog class... other than that, its all identical...

Comment: okay so i tried it with a mainWindow class in a new project and it worked... i guess its the QmainWindow that has the functionality that i want?

Comment: No, it'll work in any widget. What's probably unclear from my example above is that `centralWidget` is effectively the top level widget for  a `MainWindow`. You just need to make sure that your top level widget (whatever it is) has a layout. I suspect that my example above has led you to create a new `QWidget` in your `QDialog`, rather than `QDialog` taking the place of `centralWidget`. I'll alter my example.

Comment: okay everything works now! phew finally got this working with your much apprecipated help... I know this is something really simple but im such a noob. Thanks for your time and trouble!